# Wi-Fi indicator error after bad chown command

Tags: macos, wifi, permission

I mistakenly ran `chown -R /`.

Subsequently, I reinstalled the OS from the recovery drive (10.12.6) and ran everything I could find on the internet, including **diskutil resetUserPermissions** (`id -u`). Things are functional for the most part. However, every once in a while I hit a bizarre problem that seems to be related to permissions.

This one is the fact that my Wi-Fi indicator is totally wrong. Right now for instance, I'm on Wi-Fi in a Peet's coffee and the indicator is the exclamation point over the Wi-Fi symbol. Clicking on it says *no internet connection*. No networks appear in the list either, anywhere I go. I'm able to list networks and get online in Terminal but the commands are pretty unwieldy. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue was, but it was blown away by an upgrade to High Sierra and the wifi indicator is working again.